# Scale-invariant border-sizing in JavaFX via CSS?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm trying to specify a border size to a JavaFX node such that with the parent of the node is scaled, the resulting border still occupies the same width on screen.

For example, I have

```java
Pane container = new Pane();
Pane nodeWithBorder = new Pane();
nodeWithBorder.getStyleClass().add('my-node');
```

In my stylesheet, I have something similar to

```
.my-node {
   -fx-border-width: 2px;
   -fx-border-color: red;
   ...
}
```

Assuming `container` has `scaleX = scaleY = 1`, the resulting border for `nodeWithBorder` will render with width of 2px.

What I'd like to achieve via CSS is when `container.setScaleX(2); container.setScaleY(2)`, **the `nodeWithBorder` should correspondingly scale in size, but render with the same 2px border.**

I can do this programmatically by specifiy the border in the code and creating a binding between its width property and the scale properties. Since I need to do this in several places within my application and it's not always known which level in the parent-tree the scale is changing, I was wondering if there is a way to specify this with some-sort of relative unit via the CSS.

Comment: Scale will scale everything to do with the node, including the border, it’s just what it does.

Comment: @jewelsea I was hoping there was something like a unit specification that corresponded to actual screen pixels rather than rendered pixels (through the whole scaling mechanism). I'm assuming there's nothing that you are aware of either in that regard. None of the units in the public specs work that way as far as I tried...

Comment: Yep, your programmatic solution should work.  I don't really know how you would achieve this declaratively (I don't think there is any magic unit type which ignores scaling).  Closes thing I can think of is to try to specify the border using FXML and use a the [expression binding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#expression_binding) feature of FXML to dynamically set the border width depending upon the scale of the parent (I haven't tried that, it may not work, or if it does might be inferior to a programmatic solution anyway).